# How do I keep resources attached to a Visual Studio Solution in SVN

Tags: visual-studio-2010, svn

When I add References and place images in Expression blend, it seems to keep the location of the original file, rather then copying the data into the project itself.

How do I set these resources up in SVN so that it stays with the project and can be ran on any computer that has access to the SVN files?

Also, are there any solution or project files that I should avoid putting into svn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that it's better to Add images to project resources, and use relative source, so the projet can be run from any computer.

The following works in Visual Studio and Blend:

```
<Image Source="/MyApplication.UI.MyProject;component/Images/MyIcon.png" />
```

All file that you can add to Visual Studio source control : [File Handling by Source Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171339.aspx)